# BI Publisher: Add all columns to tabular report

Tags: bi-publisher

My company is using BI Publisher for some data dumps and I know BI Publisher isn't really designed for that, but this is what I have to use.

I have two files with over 100 fields each. Is there a way to add every field to the report or do I have to add each field individually?

Answer (score 0):

If  you have an data model export, you could use the BIP designer in word to add a table, and select multiple fields to the output. The wizard will do the xdo code for you.

Comment: I tried that and I got an error saying I can't create a table with more than 63 columns :(

Answer (score 0):

Use E-Text output. It is designed for EFT (Electronic Fund Transfers) in Payment module. But you can use it to export a CSV (Comma Separated Value) file, or a fixed width file. Both of which can be opened in Excel. The E-Text output is fully documented in the BI Publisher user guides. Some advanced stuff is a bit harder to accomplish, but it is not terribly difficult. A simple CSV file should be quick and easy to create. You will need to list every field, there's no "give me everything" command.

It's actually to your benefit to use those for larger data extracts, when you you use the Word RTF tables, the output Excel files are VERY large due to the way BI Publisher formats the cells.